# Conditional inside es6 .map

Tags: ecmascript-6, jsx

project im working on used es6/jsx and the airbnb linter but im having some trouble with the following code: i need to map items and compare it to another id but when i write it like this i get an error on the if statement, which is "parsing error unexpected token".
tried parentheses around the item, brackets after fat arrow, but not sure what the issue is. dont need to add return since it knows to expect it back. trying to find the way to get this working with the correct syntax.

```
const cartItems = items.map(item => {
  if (id === item._id) {
    console.log('found', item_id);
  }
});
```

edit:

doing it like that, the .map(item has an error: expected parentheses around arrow function having curly braces.

moving over the => { i get an error: expected to return a value in arrow function

and in the console.log the item_id has a error: item._id is not defined, it should have been defined with the map but seems its not seeing it?

basically need to loop through the items id's and match them against another set of ids, if they match i need to combine the matching ones into a new variable

Comment: curly brackets around the arrow function *body* it would be

Comment: Since your callback isn't returning anything, are you sure you want to `map` items? It looks like `filter` (with a boolean return value) or a simple `for … of` loop would be much more appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

Ive changed it a bit, for what i need by doing it like this:

```
    if (id === items.map(item => item._id)) {
     this.setState({ inCart: true });
    }
```

then just use the state value to conditionally load anything i needed.